# How to uncheck all MaterialUI Toggle components using a button or outside event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Say you have multiple `<Toggle />` components for an app that filters clothes by size. You toggle through the sizes and then you want to clear all the filters by clicking a button rather than uncheck all the toggles.

How can this be accomplished specifically with materials-ui Toggles? There's nothing in the documentation that says how you can uncheck the toggles using an outside element, such as a button.

Answer (score 0):

For this functionality, you have to maintain the state for all the Toggle component. When you click the button, then you have to update the state of all the toggles.

for eg.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
    this.state = {
      toggle1: false,
      toggle2: false,
  };
}

uncheckAllToggle = () => {
  this.setState({
    toggle1: false, 
    toggle2: false
  });
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Toggle
        label="toggle1"
        toggled={this.state.toggle1}
        onToggle={() => this.setState({toggle1: !this.state.toggle1})}
      />
      <Toggle
        label="toggle2"
        toggled={this.state.toggle2}
        onToggle={() => this.setState({toggle2: !this.state.toggle2})}
      />
     <FlatButton
       label={'UnCheck All Toggle'}
       onClick={this.uncheckAllToggle}
     />
    </div>
  )
}
```